# How does $p_0(t)\mid k(t)$?

Tags: polynomials, divisibility, minimal-polynomials

Let  $\alpha_i$ is a root of $k(t) \in \mathbb Z[t]$. Let $p_0(t)$ be the minimal polynomial of $\alpha_1$ over $\mathbb Z$. After this, it is written in a text that

> Then, we have $p_0(t)\mid k(t)$. So, $\alpha_1$ is also a root of $k(t)$.

**My question is** how we know  $p_0(t)\mid k(t)$?

**EDIT**

Let me rephrase my problem.

1. the first statement:  $\alpha_i$ is a root of $k(t) \in \mathbb Z[t]$, this is according to a previous hypothesis.
2. the second statement:  Let $p_0(t)$ be the minimal polynomial of $\alpha_1$ over $\mathbb Z$, this is true because for $\alpha_1$, there exists a minimal polynomial.
3. the third statement:   We have $p_0(t)\mid k(t)$.

Now every algebraic number $\alpha_1$ has a minimum polynomial, say $p_0$, and  if polynomial $k(t)$ has root $\alpha_1$ then  $p_0$ divides $k(t)$ (in general every polynomial that$\alpha_1$ satisfies). But at this point we don't know $\alpha_i=\alpha_1$, then how we know $p_0(t)\mid k(t)$?

4. the fourth statement: "So", $\alpha_1$ is also a root of $k(t)$

Now if we already used the fact that  $\alpha_1$ is also a root of $k(t)$ imply $p_0(t)\mid k(t)$ then how can we say $p_0(t)\mid k(t)$ implies  $\alpha_1$ is also a root of $k(t)$?

Comment: The source of the problem (see the last 2 paragraph): https://i.stack.imgur.com/vbNls.jpg

Comment: What was wrong with my answer to your previous version of the question?  It appears you have deleted it.  Is that supposed to be $\alpha_i$ in the second line, or is it $\alpha_1$ like all the rest?  If so, you started by assuming $\alpha_1$ was a root of $k(t)$

Comment: That is exactly what I answered last time.  If $\alpha_1$ is a root of $p_0(t)$, it is a root of anything $p_0(t)$ divides.

Comment: @RossMillikan  how we know  $p_0(t)\mid k(t)$?

Comment: Finally, we have a good question, which I don't know the answer to.  It is similar to unique factorization.  The claim is that for every algebraic number $\alpha$ the minimum polynomial that $\alpha$ satisfies divides every polynomial that $\alpha$ satisfies.  That implies there are not two incompatible polynomials that $\alpha$ satisfies.  Do you know that $\Bbb Z[x]$ is a unique factorization domain?

Comment: @RossMillikan mate, I know "every algebraic number α the minimum polynomial that α satisfies divides every polynomial that α satisfies." it is trivial, but then I ask how u know that $\alpha$ satisfies $k(t)$.. it looks like a circular logic.. if wealready know $\alpha$ is a root of $k(t)$ then why are we implying that at the end?? Yes i am familiar with  unique factorization, plz help to cut the clutter.

Comment: You have chosen $k(t)$ so that $\alpha$ satisfies it.  That is what $\alpha$ being a root of $k(t)$ means.  Then the theorem you quote is what you need because $p_0(t)$ is the minimal polynomial that $\alpha$ satisfies.  The text is applying this theorem.

Comment: @RossMillikan could u plz point out where I chose? In the text it is written that $\alpha_i$ not $\alpha_1$, we don't  know the $i$ for $k$.

Comment: I asked about that in a previous comment.  Presumably the subscript should stay constant through the paragraph.  As it does not, one is likely a typo.  I can't tell which without more context.

Comment: @RossMillikan This is from a thesis, the link is : https://www.scribd.com/document/471950968/Fermat-s-Last-Theorem-for-Regular-Primes-Kummer-s-Approach   ...The problem is on page 25 and 26, plz post a clear answer, i will award 50 additional rep besides accepting and voting up for clear decisive answer.

Answer (score -2):

He has constructed $k(t)$ so that $\alpha_1$ is a root of $k(t)$ by showing that $h(g(\alpha_1))=0$ and naming $k(t)=h(g(t))$.  Then if $p_0(t)$ is the minimal polynomial of $\alpha_1$, the theorem you quote in the comments "(for) every algebraic number α the minimum polynomial that α satisfies divides every polynomial that α satisfies." gives us $p_0(t)|k(t)$ because $k(\alpha_1)=0$

Comment: "gives us $p_0(t)|k(t)$ because $k(\alpha_1)=0$ " ...Oh god! not again!! Ross, my friend, this is not what the thesis says, thesis says,  "$p_0(t)|k(t)$ *So,(THEN)*  $k(\alpha_1)=0$", also note that the construction u  r talking is made upon $\alpha_i$, there is no specification in the thesis  that $i=1$ or the $\alpha_i$ is root for all $i$,   it says for **some** $\alpha_i$  .. this is the source of my confusion which i could not express properly!! :(

Comment: Also if  we know   already $k(\alpha_1)=0$, then why we need $p_0(t)|k(t)$? Are we saying $p_0(t)|k(t)$  to show  $k(\alpha_1)=0$ or $k(\alpha_1)=0$ implies  $p_0(t)|k(t)$? Which one? We don't need to show $k(\alpha_1)=0$ implies  $p_0(t)|k(t)$ because our objective is to show that $k(\alpha_1)=0$ not to show   $p_0(t)|k(t)$.

Comment: He wants to show that $k(t)$ is a power of $p_0(t)$.  First he says that $p_0(t)|k(t)$ because of the theorem.  Then he says let $k(t)=p_0^n(t)q(t)$ with $q(t)$ coprime to $p_0(t)$ and shows that $q(t)$ is constant.

Comment: The theorem u r referencing does not apply here. This is the key problem, I am sorry to say but u failed to answer at least clarify.

Comment: @Andrew Forgive me, but you're being pretty demanding of strangers' kindness and generosity while showing very little gratefulness for their time and effort. Answering you is likely to result in a lengthy and possibly stressful back-and-forth, which greatly reduces the desire of most people to answer.

Comment: @JoshuaP.Swanson there is nothing about kindness and generosity when a post had bounty and a source of gaining more reputation, we all here to either tech or learn, reputation has a role here, it is not a king's court, so don't understand why you bring up gratefulness. It is possible that answering me is likely to result in a lengthy and possibly stressful back-and-forth,which may greatly reduces the desire of most people to answer, I understand but  no one is forced here, I think you are overreacting, everybody is not as intelligent as you, you should be patient.

Answer (score -2):

I think the result that you require is this one. Since $\alpha_i$ is a root of $k(t)\in Z[t]$, we can apply the embedding that carries to $\alpha_i$ to $\alpha_1$, say $\sigma$, to the polynomial $k(t)$. If $\alpha_i$ is a root of $k(t)$, then $\sigma(\alpha_i)=\alpha_1$ is a root of $\sigma(k(t))=k(t)$. This happens because $0=\sigma(0)=\sigma(k(\alpha_i))=k(\sigma(\alpha_i))=k(\alpha_1)$.

Therefore, your $\alpha_1$ also satisfies the same polynomial $k(t)$ and is a root. So, the minimal polynomial of $\alpha_1$ must divide it. Can you take it from here?

Comment: Hi Umesh. thanks for ur answer, but  I have 2 issues: **1.** the embedding you are refereeing is not mentioned  in the paragraph (last paragraph on page 25), it does not look like the author used that embedding to say $p_0(t)|k(t)$ **2.** The author first proved that $p_0(t)|k(t)$ then implies $\alpha_1$ is root (look the first line on page 26), not that the author proved $\alpha_1$ is a root then implied $p_o(t)|k(t)$, plz reconsider. Link: https://www.scribd.com/document/471950968/Fermat-s-Last-Theorem-for-Regular-Primes-Kummer-s-Approach

Comment: I read the proof in the link before I gave the answer. The embedding is mentioned in same proof right before equation 4.1. I'm aware that he doesn't make use of the arguement explicitly. But he has indeed used the arguement. This arguement, however, is one where my professors just believed that we would know. If this argument was applied in my courses, it was almost never explicitly stated.

Comment: The problem is it looks like there is another reasoning, the way it is written, I mean my second point, The author first proved that $p_0(t)|k(t)$ then implies $α_1$ is root (look the first line on page 26), not that the author proved $α_1$ is a root then implied $po(t)|k(t)$, so  I cant accept your answer, if I accept $\alpha_1$ is a root then I dont need to post this question, i hope you understand.

Comment: If this link doesn't clear this up, I don't know what will. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1160606/is-it-true-that-all-the-roots-of-the-minimal-polynomial-of-alpha-are-galois-c

Comment: I understand what you say, but could u plz explain what is the point of saying $p_0(t)|k(t)$ in text  if we already know (by using embedding) that $\alpha_1$ is a root?

Comment: I think you'd be happier if the author used the minimal polynomial of $\xi^i/ \xi^{p-i}$ and then showed that the minimal polynomial of $\xi / \xi^{p-1}$ divides it and then proceeded with his proof. But this thesis that you're reading is hardly the be-all and end-all of Algebraic number theory. We have to admit that he's made a small mistake and move on.

Comment: I did not answer this question because I was in dire need of reputation (though I certainly wouldn't say no to it xD). I only answered because you seemed intent to understand this material better. I hope this has been achieved even if you don't accept my answer. Cheers, mate!

Comment: If we take your suggestion then saying $\alpha_i$ is a root of $k(t)$ implies that $\alpha_1$ is also a root of $k(t)$ due to the embedding, **we don't need** $p_0|k(t)$, the statement $p_0|k(t)$ is absolutely redundant to say $\alpha_1$ is a root of $k(t)$, isn't  it?

Comment: Yup, I'd say so.

Comment: you wrote an  embedding exists  that carries to $\alpha_i$ to $\alpha_1$, say $\sigma$, in the polynomial $k(t)$... is there any lemma/ theorem or is there anything on that thesis through we can prove it rigorously ?

Comment: Page no. 24, after notation 4.1.